# Google Maps SDK with thousands of different markers goes out of memory

Tags: android, google-maps, bitmap, crash

I need to make a map with thousands (~1500) `Markers` on it. Each marker has a unique `Bitmap`, as the icon has text below it to show some information (which may be unique).

Unfortunately, the app crashes due to memory problems when loading so many different Bitmaps.

Clustering is not an option.
Also rendering only markers which are visible in the viewport does not work, as it needs to much CPU to handle so many elements.

I am already using an LRU Cache for caching Bitmaps which are the same.
Is there any advice you can give me to achieve my goal?Thanks!!

Comment: Try reduce the size of each bitmap?

Comment: try to show icons in difference zoom level

Comment: unfortunately changing icons with zoom level does not help, as i need also to show all markers at the same time and then the re-rendering is too slow and blocks the UI